# Проблема с дополнительным шрифтом

Tags: c#, winforms

Я указываю шрифт для кнопки a_Simpler
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это шрифт не добавлен в библиотеку шрифтов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То она пишет обычным шрифтом Microsoft Sans Serif

Можно ли сохранить шрифт a_Simpler вместе с .exe? или как решить проблему?

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: c# WindowsForms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компиляция из ответов на en.SO:

Трюк состоит в том, чтобы положить шрифт в глобальную [`PrivateFontCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx), и использовать его оттуда. (Саму коллекцию, судя по всему, нужно положить в главный класс приложения или другое общедоступное место.)

Если он уже там у вас есть, и коллекция определена как `PrivateFontCollection pfc`, используйте такую конструкцию:

```
b.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], <тут указываете размер>);
```

Ещё нужно установить в свойствах UI-элемента `UseCompatibleTextRendering` в `true`.

Вместо индекса 0 может понадобиться другой, если вы кладёте в коллекцию несколько шрифтов.

---

Как можно добавить шрифт в коллекцию? Для этого используются методы `AddFontFile` и `AddMemoryFont`. Если вы таскаете шрифт в файле, то всё совсем просто: `pfc.AddFontFile(<тут путь к вашему файлу со шрифтом>);`.

Если вы решили положить шрифт в ресурсы, понадобится более сложный код.

```
var fontdata = Properties.Resources.Simpler; // Simpler - имя, которое вы дали шрифту
var length = fontdata.Length;                // в ресурсах
var unsafeData = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(length);
Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, unsafeData, length);
pfc.AddMemoryFont(unsafeData, length);
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(unsafeData);
```

---

Источники: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1297264/276994), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/556147/276994), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1956043/276994), [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3007805/276994).

Comment: `b.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], <тут указываете размер>);` Можно ли как то взять стандартный размер? а не указывать его.

Comment: @Sauron: Например, `b.Font.Size`?

Comment: Нет я имею веду поменять только ширифт а размер оставить стандартным.

Comment: @Sauron: А вы попробуйте! До присвоения `b.Font = ...` там стандартный шрифт, у которого стандартный размер.

Comment: @Sauron, @VladD, класс `Font`, судя по примерам в MSDN неизменяемый, поэтому размер, жирность, тип и другие параметры шрифта приходится задавать при создании и устанавливать новый шрифт вместо изменения существующего. Видимо идея как со строками, раз на один экземпляр может быть много ссылок - менять запрещено, создавайте заново.