# Установить шрифт в Windows Form

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, label

Недавно начал разбираться с Windows Form(C++/Cli), и столкнулся с такой штукой. При выборе шрифта для label-а, многие шрифты не отображаются, а точнее выглядят как дефолтный. Хотелось бы узнать, как это можно поправить, или это так и должно быть?

**Но основная проблема не в этом**, больше меня интересует такой вопрос.

Вот хочу я установить свой шрифт(.ttf), допустим, скачанный с интернета. Как это можно сделать? И от чего зависит, будет ли он отображаться в Windows Form?

Comment: А почему возник интерес к C++/CLI? Это по работе надо?

Comment: Все намного проще. Еще школьником увлекался олимпиадным программированием. И вот решил посмотреть на Windows Form. Как позже оказалось, язык на котором я стал писать оказался как раз таки c++/CLI:)

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы шрифт можно было выбрать в виндовс форм, Нужно просто установить его в виндос. 
Для того нужно или нажать на шрифт и кликнуть установить или
просто скопировать  его в папку C:\Windows\Fonts, 
Не забудьте закрыть а потом открыть визуальный после установки шрифта.

**При запуске программы на другом пк**
Но помните что шрифт не будет отображаться в системе где он не установлен, то этому ваша программа должна проверять его наличие и устанавливать, или как то нужно привязать файл шрифта к пашей откомпилированной программы но этого другой вопрос и пока я не знаю ответа.

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746555/184217), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535734/184217), [3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-private-font-collection).