# Windows Forms, Добавление шрифта в программу

Tags: c#, winforms, шрифты

Всем доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: всем элементам (лэйблам, листбоксам и пр) установил скачанный из интернета шрифт, на моём компуктере всё работает, а на других, логично, нет.
Прочтение других вопросов на стэковерфлоу и сторонних статей (в первую очередь [этой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303(v=vs.100).aspx)) понимания не дало. Самый понятный вариант, который я видел - хранение шрифта в .resx файле, но инструкции его создания для дальнейшего редактирования я тоже не нашёл - только предостережение, что ручное создание может привести к ошибкам.

Подскажите, как либо добавить шрифт в саму программу, либо как на него сослаться, положив в ту же директорию, что и .exe файл?
(вообще хотелось бы добавить в программу, но в данном случае пойдёт и положить рядом, так как всё равно с .exe уже лежит .xml с данными)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто положите шрифт в папку/подпапку вашего приложения. С учётом того, что это WinForms, используем `PrivateFontCollection`.

```
// Устанавливаем нужный шрифт
PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
fontCollection.AddFontFile("font.ttf"); // файл шрифта
FontFamily family = fontCollection.Families[0];
// Создаём шрифт и используем далее
Font font = new Font(family, 15);
```