# Кастомный шрифт

Tags: c#

Использую в проекте свой кастомный шрифт, в свойствах текст бокса указал его, но я так понимаю он будет только у меня работать.

[image: Скрин]

Или как? Совсем недавно начал заниматься этим, и не совсем понимаю. Подскажите, спасибо.

Comment: зачем это спрашивать, легче проверить

Comment: Действительно. Я уже проверил. Если шрифт не установлен на пк открывается программа со стандартным шрифтом. Вопрос в том, как сделать чтобы человек не устанавливал шрифт а он работал в программе.

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297264/using-custom-fonts-on-a-label-on-winforms

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746555/184217

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297264/using-custom-fonts-on-a-label-on-winforms вот по этой ссылке в пункте 3 не совсем понятно. Как и где создать функцию.