# C# Обмен данными между UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

У меня есть UserControl1 и UserControl2. В UserControl2 стоит FontDialog.
Мне нужно, чтобы текст изменился во всей программе, а не только в UserControl2.

Comment: [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746555/343103)

Comment: Мне нужно поменять цвет, шрифт, размер.

Comment: Ну заведите класс с настройками, пусть все контролы его используют, его и меняйте

Comment: В цикле или рекурсивно пробегаете по _всем_ контролам и меняете шрифт.

Answer (score 0):

Тип `System.Drawing.Font` не позволяет менять свои свойства, только заменять объект целиком, поэтому никаких вариантов, кроме ручного обхода нужных контролов и ручной установки им нового шрифта нет.

Для кастомных `UserContorl` можно сделать класс `Settings` с полем `Font` (ну и что там еще понадобится, цвет например), реализовать в данном классе интерфейс [INotfyPropertyChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8), добавить ссылку на единственный инстанс данного класса (реализовать как синглтон?) во все `UserContorl` и подписаться на событие изменения поля `Font`. Тогда изменив шрифт в настройках - он поменяется во всех, подписанных на это событие, контролах. Однако даже такой подход не избавит от необходимость ручного прописывания нового шрифта вложенным контролам.

Если хотите менять стиль оформления налету в WinForms - либо все-все-все руками, либо берете готовый фреймворк с поддержкой стилей, вроде DevExpress, перестаете страдать от ручной реализации поддержки стилей и начинаете страдать от "тараканов", ой простите, "уникальных особенностей" выбранного фреймворка, разрастания количества сторонних библиотек, которые вы не используете напрямую или вообще не используете, но не можете выкинуть потому что фреймворк и т.д. и т.п.